# RegExp javascript : authorize slash

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a RegExp to format an URL in a HTML input. 
I want to remove all character which are not letters or numbers.

So I write this regexp :

```
return url.toLowerCase()
            .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "") 
            .replace(/[_|\s]+/g, "-") 
            .replace(/[^a-z\u0400-\u04FF0-9-]+/g, "") 
            .replace(/[-]+/g, "-") 
            .replace(/^-+|-+$/g, "")
            .replace(/[-]+/g, "-");
```

But now, I want to accept the slash character ( / ). How can I accept this character through my replaces ? I am not very sure about RegExp.

I want this string :

> Category / Test name = dog

To become :

> category/test-name-dog

Comment: Perhaps, `.replace(/[^a-z\/\u0400-\u04FF0-9-]+/g, "")`?

Comment: It doesn't work, my slashes are still replaced.

Comment: You are accepting slashes in this line `replace(/\/+/g, "/")`

Comment: It was one of my try, but didn't work.

Comment: But if you "remove all characters which are not letters or numbers" then you're changing the url and it won't work anymore.

Comment: The question is very unclear, sorry. Please add one or two example strings with expected output.

Comment: Added an example of what I want.

Comment: You will at least need what @WiktorStribiżew pointed out. this section currently matches `/` and remove them

Comment: Tested all the other replacements and none other than the third match the slashes.

Comment: Does [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/21uww65p/) work for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you don't need to escape the slash inside a class btw. It doesn't match \ either but it's just superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to follow your logic, you need to "protect" the `/` symbol in the negated character class (here - `/[^a-z\/\u0400-\u04FF0-9-]+/g` - so that you do not remove it too early), and then replace all `-/-` with just `/` as a final step. Note that you are duplicating `.replace(/[-]+/g, "-")` step, you can remove the first one.

```
return url.toLowerCase()
            .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "") 
            .replace(/[_\s]+/g, "-") 
            .replace(/[^a-z\/\u0400-\u04FF0-9-]+/g, "") 
            .replace(/^-+|-+$/g, "")
            .replace(/-+/g, "-")
            .replace(/-*\/-*/g, "/");
```

```js
url = "Category / Test name = dog";
document.body.innerHTML = "Old: " + url.toLowerCase()
            .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "") 
            .replace(/[_|\s]+/g, "-") 
            .replace(/[^a-z\u0400-\u04FF0-9-]+/g, "") 
            .replace(/[-]+/g, "-") 
            .replace(/^-+|-+$/g, "")
            .replace(/[-]+/g, "-");
            // and now
document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>New: " + url.toLowerCase()
            .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "") 
            .replace(/[_\s]+/g, "-") 
            .replace(/[^a-z\/\u0400-\u04FF0-9-]+/g, "") 
            .replace(/^-+|-+$/g, "")
            .replace(/-+/g, "-")
            .replace(/-*\/-*/g, "/");
```